# Extension vs Subclass. How to explain different behavior when I set background color for UIButton

Tags: swift

I want to change background color for UIButton in highlighted state. 
I use two different ways.

Case #1 with extension:

```
extension UIButton {

override open func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    backgroundColor = .green

    setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
}

override open var isHighlighted :Bool {
    didSet{
        if isHighlighted {
            backgroundColor = .red
        } else {
            backgroundColor = .green
        }
    }
}
}
```

[image: Normal state] 
[image: Highlighted state]

Case #2 with subclass:

```
class SHButton: UIButton {

override open func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    backgroundColor = .green

    setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
}


override open var isHighlighted :Bool {
    didSet{
        if isHighlighted {
            backgroundColor = .red
        } else {
            backgroundColor = .green
        }
    }
}
}
```

[image]
[image: Highlited state for subclass]

I use very similar code, but I see different results in runtime.
In second case button title has not a white color.

Why we can see so different results in runtime?

Updated. This question has been resolved. I'm dummy. I forgot to change button **Type**  to **Custom**.  When I have did it both examples began to work identically.

Comment: What are the differences in the results? It's hard to tell just from your code.

Comment: From the "Extensions" section of the "The Swift Programming Language" book: *"“Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality.”*

Comment: I am Sorry, I hastened to put the post. Give me a few minutes to correct post.

Comment: Ah. Obviously, *awakeFromNib()* isn't executing in the subclass. Now the question is why? Since you are using UIKit, I'm guessing it has to do with overriding *init(frame:)* and or *init(coder:)* instead of *awakeFromNib()*. That's a solution, but it doesn't **answer** why the extension works. Maybe @rmaddy is correct. (I - English-only speaking with fair to good grammar - find it somewhat confusing the quote made in that comment. If you can override in an extension, how isn't that adding new functionality? Besides, the extension works!)

Answer (score 0):

this should also fix your problem

```
button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .highlighted)
```

Comment: I think that it is not necessary. Apple docs say  "if a (color) property is not specified for a state, the default is to use the normal value."